# PyAudio readframes not ending when wav file completes

Tags: python, pyaudio

Currently doing some experimenting with PyAudio. My current goal is to import a wav file and get PyAudio to play it for me. Playing it is actually the easy part - the hard part is getting the stream to close once the wav file is complete. Right now my code never exits the while loop. I hear the wav file and then silence as the code continues to write nothing to the stream.

```
import wave
import pyaudio

wav = wave.open('./5secondbeat.wav')
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
chunk = 1024
stream = p.open(format = p.get_format_from_width(wav.getsampwidth()),
                channels = wav.getnchannels(),
                rate = wav.getframerate(),
                frames_per_buffer = chunk,
                output = True)

data = wav.readframes(chunk)
while data != '':    //enters this loop
    stream.write(data)    //I hear my short 5 second wave file
    data = wav.readframes(chunk)

print('hello')    //this never gets printed and my code continues running in the loop

stream.close() 
p.terminate()
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data types in your conditional don't correspond.  You could try one of these to cast them to the same type before checking:

```
while data != b'':
```

or

```
while data.decode("utf-8") != '':
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks you. Any idea why my data type doesn't correspond to the type in most of the documentation I see online? I have only ever seen !=''

Comment: I suspect the documentation may be targeted for python 2, and I'll hazard that like me, you are running python 3?  String types have been made more strictly standardized in python 3, so that what I suspect https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#text-versus-binary-data